# How to select multiple images from gallery with expo or expo-image-picker-multiple

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, file-upload, expo

I have been trying since 3 days ago to see how i can select multiple images using any package that works wit expo but to no avail, I ave tried ImagePicker but only allows one picture to be selected, tried couple of other packages but keep getting errors, I also have been trying expo-image-picker-multiple latest version but it keeps showing errors.

Answer (score 1):

So  i was finally able to select multiple image from gallery and upload using below
to get expo-image-picker-multiple to work, use version 1.0.6 and then go to the source file  in node modules and find ImageBrowser file  and replace the prepareCallback function with below code

```
prepareCallback() {
const { selected, photos } = this.state;
const selectedPhotos = selected.map(i => photos[i]);
  this.props.callback(selectedPhotos); }
```

and then go to ImageBrowserScreen file and replace imagesCallback function wit below code

```
imagesCallback = (photos) => {
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.props.navigation.setOptions({
  headerRight: () => this._getHeaderLoader()
});
     console.log(2);
   const cPhotos = [];
  for(let photo of photos) {
     cPhotos.push({
      uri: photo.uri,
      name: photo.filename,
      type: 'image/jpg'
    })
  }
  console.log(3);
  console.log(cPhotos);
  navigation.navigate('post_ad', {photos: cPhotos}); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Expo SDK 46+ and you are able to set the ImagePicker to grab multiple files (works on Web, Android and IOS14+).

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsMultipleSelection: true,
            selectionLimit: 4,
          });
```

The response contains `uri` for each file (among other data).

```
result.map(async (img) => {
                const url = await handleImageUpload(img.uri)
            })
```

The [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) is excellent.